# PhoneGap & Connecting to SQLite Database via Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, sqlite, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm fairly new to PhoneGap and am building am stuck on connecting to an existing SQLite database. Below is my code. Through log entries and alerts, I've noticed that the javascript is running its course, but it's apparent that my openDatabase call isn't fully setup appropriately. The error I'm getting is "error: could not prepare statement (1 no such table: person) (Code 5)"

```
if(openDatabase){
                 db = openDatabase('popfon.sqlite'
                                    , '1.0'
                                    , 'Database Description'
                                    , 200000;
    }
                  //Alert the user to upgrade their browser
                  else {
                  alert('Databases not supported. Please get a proper browser');
                  }
  $JQuery("#theButton").click(function(){getData()});

function getData(){
    //Create an empty results string
    var strResults = '';
    //Open a new transaction
    db.transaction(function(tx){
                   //Select a wildcard from the database
                   var theQuery = "SELECT * FROM person where OfficialName like '%law%'"
                   alert(theQuery);
                   tx.executeSql(theQuery
                                 ,[]
                                 //Callback function with transaction and
                                 //results objects
                                 ,function(tx, results){
                                 //Count the results rows
                                 var rowsCount = results.rows.length;
                               //  alert("rowsCount: "+rowsCount);
                                 //Loop the rows
                                 for (var i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++){
                                 //Build a results string, notice the
                                 //column names are called
                                 strResults += 'Your Name is'
                                 + results.rows.item(i).personName
                                 + ' Your ID is '
                                 + results.rows.item(i).personId
                                 + ' Your age is '
                                 + results.rows.item(i).personAge
                                 + ' Your favourite colour is '
                                 + results.rows.item(i).personColour
                                 + '';
                                 }
                                 //Fill the results DIV
                                 $('.results').html(strResults);
                                 }
                                 ,errorHandler);
                   });
}
```

Comment: And where do you create the `person` table?

Comment: @CL I don't...it exists in my sqlite table that is filled with a ton of data...

Comment: I was hoping to be able to just connect and with it as it exists...without having to rebuild

Comment: How do you get that database file into the web browser's private directory on the client?

Comment: i manually placed it in the file structure when building the app. Although, as i look into this more I'm seeing that won't work.

Basically, my db has > 3000 rows and I don't want to run create. I'd like to have it come bundled with the app when downloaded. I'm trying to access it via javascript...avoiding ObjectiveC entirely.